# Search block does not work in Drupal

Tags: php, search, xhtml, drupal-6, themes

I just uploaded a test site on the following location : www.betterclassofleaders.co.cc/whackk
I am using a customised search block (customised through search-theme-form.tpl.php) but it does not work. If you type in a search term and hit Enter it will go to the search result page but without actually performing the search.

Searching through the results page does work as normal. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: please provide search-theme-form.tpl.php template  file. i think you might have been forgotten the form action.

Comment: <input type="text" name="search_theme_form_keys" id="edit-search-theme-form-keys" value="Search" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for" class="logininput" height="24px" onblur="restoreSearch(this)" onfocus="clearInput(this)" />
  <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="" class="form-submit" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-search-theme-form-form-token" value="<?php print drupal_get_token('search_theme_form'); ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-search-theme-form" value="search_theme_form" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot directly modify the HTML in `search-theme-form.tpl.php` since thats not the right way to do it. So my adding the class and onFocus and onBlur attributes was the problem.

The correct way to do it is to modify the themes `template.php` file. Basically we will be using `form_alter()` to modify the form elements. Since using the HTML way is wrong. Take a look at the code below (taken from : [here](http://drupal.org/node/45295) )

```
<?php
/**
* Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the search_theme_form template.
*
* @param $vars
*   A sequential array of variables to pass to the theme template.
* @param $hook
*   The name of the theme function being called (not used in this case.)
*/
function yourthemename_preprocess_search_theme_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Note that in order to theme a search block you should rename this function
  // to yourthemename_preprocess_search_block_form and use
  // 'search_block_form' instead of 'search_theme_form' in the customizations
  // bellow.

  // Modify elements of the search form
  $vars['form']['search_theme_form']['#title'] = t('');

  // Set a default value for the search box
  $vars['form']['search_theme_form']['#value'] = t('Search this Site');

  // Add a custom class and placeholder text to the search box
  $vars['form']['search_theme_form']['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'NormalTextBox txtSearch', 
                                                              'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Search this Site') {this.value = '';}",
                                                              'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search this Site';}");

  // Change the text on the submit button
  //$vars['form']['submit']['#value'] = t('Go');

  // Rebuild the rendered version (search form only, rest remains unchanged)
  unset($vars['form']['search_theme_form']['#printed']);
  $vars['search']['search_theme_form'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['search_theme_form']);

  $vars['form']['submit']['#type'] = 'image_button';
  $vars['form']['submit']['#src'] = path_to_theme() . '/images/search.jpg';

  // Rebuild the rendered version (submit button, rest remains unchanged)
  unset($vars['form']['submit']['#printed']);
  $vars['search']['submit'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['submit']);

  // Collect all form elements to make it easier to print the whole form.
  $vars['search_form'] = implode($vars['search']);
}
?>
```

In `yourthemename_preprocess_search_theme_form` - 'yourthemename' will obviously reflect the name of your custom theme. Basically the code is self-explanatory. what with the comments and all.

So, basically thats the way it works.